# Shortest distance between a point and a parabola.

Tags: optimization, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, maxima-minima

Find the shortest distance from the point $(1, 0)$ to the parabola $y^2 = 4x$.

As-

Let $D^2=(x-1)^2 + y^2$. Now reduce this to one variable by putting $y^2 = 4x$ to get  $D^2 = (x-1)^2+ 4x$. We are working with $D^2$ to  make the  calculations easier. Clearly $$\frac{d}{dx}D^2 = 2(x-1)+4 = 0 \implies x = -1$$ At $x = -1$, we have $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}D^2 = 2 < 0$ which shows that $D^2$ is minimum. At this $x = -1$.

But this is not a point on parabola. Am i doing some mistake or we have to follow some other method to get the minima?

Comment: **Hint:** $(x-1)^2+4x=(x+1)^2$

Comment: $y^2=x$ implies $x \ge 0$.Rule out $x=-1$.Only solutions with $x\ge 0$ are allowed.

Comment: How to proceed then?

Comment: Also note that $2\gt0.$ Additionally, $D=x+1 \implies \frac d{dx} D=1\implies \frac {d^2}{dx^2} =0$

Comment: Also see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315718/find-the-shortest-distance-between-the-point-and-a-parabola) post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

$$D^2=(x+1)^2$$
$$=(\frac{y^2}{4}+1)^2$$

$D$ is minimal when $y=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\left(\frac{y^2}{4},y\right)$ be a point on our parabola.

Thus, we need to find a minimal value of the following expression.
$$\sqrt{\left(\frac{y^2}{4}-1\right)^2+y^2},$$ which is equal to $1$ for $y=0$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that:
$$\left(\frac{y^2}{4}-1\right)^2+y^2\geq1$$ or
$$\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^4}{16}\geq0,$$ which is obvious.